# What is the optimal upper bound of $|T_1|+|T_2|+|T_3|$ if $T_1, T_2, T_3$ are trees covering a planar graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, combinatorial-optimization, extremal-graph-theory

By a classical theorem of Nash-Williams, the edges of every connected $n$-vertex planar graph can be covered by three trees $T_1,T_2$ and $T_3$. Does anyone know of any results from an article or a textbook on the upper bound of $|T_1|+|T_2|+|T_3|$ in terms of $n$? Thank you in advance!

ps. $|T_i|$ denoes the number of vertices of $T_i$.

Comment: you probably mean that the graph is connected?

Comment: Yes, the graph is connected (now I add this condition to the main text). Thanks.

Comment: The answer (assuming that $|T|$ denotes the number of edges in $T$) is between $3n-6$ (we may have as many edges in total) and $3n-3$ (any tree has at most $n-1$ edges).

Comment: You are right but in my mind $|T_i|$ denoes the number of vertices of $T_i$. Sorry for this confusion and I made it clear in the text.

Comment: well, It's not crucial at all, just add 3 to the above bounds.

Comment: @FedorPetrov  Are you assuming the trees are edge-disjoint? That's not how  I interpret the question, and I don't think the theorem is true with that restriction.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay no, I do not assume this. The upper bound $3n-3$ and the lower bound $3n-6$ hold for the total number of three trees with common edges as well.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks, I get it now.